# MDX calculation of an Average Over Time with delta update on the fact table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am having a problem creating this MDX calculation :

- Average Price of products over time knowing that my fact table gets price updates incrementally;

In order to calculate the average price of products at a certain point in time I have to lookup back to the latest prices of all the products (not all of the products necessarily get price updates at that point in time).

My fact table looks something like this :

**F_Products**

```
(Product_key,Date_Key,Price,flag_PriceChanged)
```

**Dim_Products**

```
(Product_key,ProductID,Price)
```

I had a success solving this using Chris Webb's [last ever non empty solution](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach) but it gets dramatically slower whenever I apply it on large set of products or over a large period of time.

The Calculations that I've used look something like this :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].DAYSTODATE AS
IIF([Measures].[Price]=NULL, NULL,  
COUNT(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER)-1);   

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].HADSALE AS   
IIF([Measures].[Price]=NULL, NULL, MEASURES.DAYSTODATE);      

SCOPE([Measures].MAXDATE, [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS);       
    THIS = MAX(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER, MEASURES.HADSALE);      
END SCOPE;      

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].LASTSALE AS  
IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].MAXDATE), NULL,   
([Measures].[Sales Price],  
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS.ITEM(MEASURES.MAXDATE)));      

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Average Price Incl. VAT]   
AS  
IIF( [Measures].HADSALE = NULL,NULL,  
    AVG([Dim Products].[Product ID].[Product ID],MEASURES.LASTSALE*1.25));
```

Any help Would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the obvious attribute relationships on your [date] dimension?

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not sure what you mean exactly but my fact table is bounded to a couple of Date role playing dimensions. One of the hierarchies built in the [date] dimension is : **(Date_key->Calendar Year Number ->Cakendar Month name -> Cakendar Day number)** I guess those are the attribute relationships that you mentioned

Comment: No, on the dimension editing interface you have a tab, attribute relationships. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms174878.aspx are they defined on your date dimension?

Comment: Yes, the attribute relationships are defined.